# Even good query failed to catch duplicate rows in Oracle

Tags: c#, database, oracle, stored-functions

It is about checking duplicate rows after inserted. I know you would say why not checking first before inserting, but we cannot do it for some reasons. We are using Oracle 12c.

When finding more than one same entries (transactionNumber and vendor as unique), the first entry with the **earliest time** should be passed as 'Success' Status and the other entries with the **latest time** should be rejected as 'Duplicate' status.

See the below picture.

[image]

[image]

This query seems useful, but sometimes it doesn't catch a duplicate row. When running a console app (C#) to load 1000 data, I end up getting 2 duplicates out of 1000. In production, we got less than 15 duplicates out of 50 000. I know its not bad, but is there a way to do better than this query? No duplicates AT ALL!

Oracle DB seems out of control or am I doing something wrong with this query? Should we create index for this query? Any advice?

```
function checkDuplicate(i_vendor varchar2,i_transactionnumber varchar2, i_txId 
raw) return number 
is
    transactionId raw(16);
    o_result number;
BEGIN
    select tx.id into transactionId from (select tx.id,row_number() over (order by tx.trans_time asc) as seqnum
    from test_tx_log tx
    where tx.transactionnumber = i_transactionnumber and lower(tx.vendor) = lower(i_vendor)) tx where seqnum = 1;

    o_result := CASE transactionId = i_txId WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

    return o_result;

 END;
```

My table is:

```
  Create TABLE test_tx_log
  (
   id                  RAW(16) not null,
   status              VARCHAR2 (300) NOT NULL,
   trans_time          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   receiptnumber       VARCHAR2 (100) NULL,
   transactionnumber   VARCHAR2 (120) NULL,
   customerreference   VARCHAR2 (100) NULL,
   vendor              VARCHAR2 (100) NULL
   ) ;
```

C#

```
    public bool CheckDuplicate3()
    {
        DbConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = GetFactory().CreateConnection();
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = "user id=XXXX;password=XXXX;data source=XXXX";
                connection.Open();
                using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "mca_test_package.checkDuplicate";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.AddParameter("o_result", DbType.Decimal, 0, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
                    command.AddParameter("i_vendor", DbType.String, tx.Vendor);
                    command.AddParameter("i_transactionnumber", DbType.String, tx.TransactionNumber.Trim());
                    command.AddParameter("i_txId", DbType.Binary, tx.Id.ToByteArray(), ParameterDirection.Input, 16);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var result = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["o_result"].Value);

                    if (result == 1)
                    {
                        tx.status = "Success";
                        Console.WriteLine("No Duplicate {0}", tx);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate {0}", tx);
                        tx.status = "RejectedDuplicate";
                    }
                }

                using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = "update test_tx_log tx set tx.status = :status where id = :id";
                    command.AddParameter("status", DbType.String, tx.status);
                    //command.AddParameter("id", DbType.Decimal, tx.Id);
                    command.AddParameter("id", DbType.Binary, tx.Id.ToByteArray());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"we cannot do it for some reasons"*  Because it's so much easier to clean up a corrupted database than prevent the  corruption in the first place?

Comment: Try `row_number() over (partition by tx.vendor, tx.transactionnumber order by tx.trans_time, tx.id) as seqnum` it looks like if there are other transactions on the same time but for different vendor these are included in your partition window.

Comment: The vendor is being filtered out.

Comment: Sample data would help a lot.

Comment: I did copy the data above into an Oracle table and tested the query.  I did not get the correct id when the id wasn't in the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Change `(select tx.id,row_number() over (order by  tx.trans_time asc) as seqnum`

to

`(select tx.id,row_number() over (order by tx.trans_time, tx.id asc) as seqnum`

Sort by trans_time, tx.id not just trans_time.

Without an order by there's no guaranteed order returned so the order of the ID in your query is random within trans_time.

In your example,
When you call the function with the first ID, the first ID is the first seqnum and matches.

When you call the function with the second ID, the second ID is the first seqnum and also matches.

Adding the ID to the order by will guarantee ID 1 is seqnum 1 for both calls within the earliest trans_time.

Comment: i followed your advice...and ran the console app with your query. I got a below result. It seems not working. Got 3 duplicates:             80D192B392294A68E05400144FFA906A 268 Mary5 Success 01/FEB/19 10:03:58.000000000
80D1925A68EF49E5E05400144FFA906A 268 Mary5      Success 01/FEB/19 10:04:09.000000000
80D1929DC5884A54E05400144FFA906A 268 Mary5      Success 01/FEB/19 10:04:09.000000000
80D1927EC2D34A49E05400144FFA906A 268 Mary5      RejectedDuplicate 01/FEB/19 10:04:58.000000000
80D1929E4C544A5CE05400144FFA906A 268 Mary5      RejectedDuplicate 01/FEB/19 10:05:14.000000000

Comment: Make sure the order by is tran_time, id.  I originally had id, trans_time.  You need to sort by the time first.

Comment: Yes I did sort by the time first - trans_time, id asc. No luck! :(

Comment: Change function to a procedure and return the status and the transaction id returned from the query. Print out the two ID's being compared so you can see the behavior of the sort. Or add dbms_output.put_line to the function and use a procedure instead of C# (as a test stub). I'd also try partitioning by vendor, transactionnumber as @Dominic Colton suggested